# Pass selected checkboxes from popup window to text input on a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a dynamic table the user add's rows to by clicking the Add row button. In the row i have a button 'Select Scope' that opens a new window full of checkbox's I'm trying to get all of the selected checkbox's values to post to a text input in the dynamic table from the parent page. [Dynamic Table Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hazS.jpg)[Select Scope Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2AfW.jpg) I know that this is possible just using javascript and I feel like I am on the right track from everything that I have read. For whatever reason though it's not passing the checkbox values back to the text input.

**Parent Page Code**

```
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
        <form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
            <p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete last row.</p>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add"/>
             <input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Delete"/>



            <br>

            <table id="myTable" class="form">

                 <tr id="heading">
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Unit Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Code</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Model Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Scope</font></b></th>
                </tr>   

                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobNumber[]" value="<?php echo $JobNumber;?>" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value="<?php echo $JobNumber;?>-01" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="JobCode[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                            <option></option>
                            <option>F</option>
                            <option>FS</option>
                            <option>PD</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ModelNumber[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                    </td>

        <td>
            <button onclick="ScopeFunction()">Select Scope</button>
            <input type"text" name="Scope[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C">

        </td>

               </tr>

            </table>


            <script>

function incrementUnitId(unitId) {
    var arr = unitId.split('-');
    if (arr.length === 1) {return;} // The unit id is not valid;
    var number = parseInt(arr[1]) + 1;
    return arr[0] + '-' + (number < 10 ? 0 : '') + number;
    }

function addRow() {                
    var row = document.getElementById("tableRow"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    row.id = "oldRow"; // We want to take the last value inserted
    clone.cells[1].childNodes[1].value = incrementUnitId(clone.cells[1].childNodes[1].value)
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }


function deleteRow() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
    }

 var popup;
 function SelectScope() {
 window.open("http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmSelectScope.php", "_blank",     "width=550,height=875");
popup.focus();
 }


     </script>
```

**EDITED Popup Window Code**

```
        <h1>Select Scope</h1>
<h3>Select all that apply</h3>
        <form name="childForm" id="updateParent();">

        <li><input type="checkbox" name="S1" value="100OA"/><font size="4">100OA</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S2" value="BTank"/><font size="4">BTank</font>
             <input type="checkbox" name="S3" value="WSEcon"/><font size="4">WSEcon</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S4" value="NetPkg"/><font size="4">NetPkg</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S5" value="CstmCtrl"/><font size="4">CstmCtrl</font>
               <br><br>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="S6" value="CstmRef"/><font size="4">CstmRef</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S7" value="CstmSM"/><font size="4">CstmSM</font>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="S8" value="CstmHV"/><font size="4">CstmHV</font>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="S9" value="CPCTrl"/><font size="4">CPCtrl</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S10" value="DesiHW"/><font size="4">DesiHW</font>
                    <br><br>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="S11" value="DigScroll"/><font size="4">DigScroll</font>
             <input type="checkbox" name="S12" value="DFGas"/><font size="4">DFGas</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S13" value="DWall"/><font size="4">DWall</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S14" value="MZ-DD"/><font size="4">MZ-DD</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S15" value="DPP"/><font size="4">DPP</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S16" value="Encl"/><font size="4">Encl</font>
                 <br><br>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="S17" value="PlateHX"/><font size="4">PlateHX</font>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="S18" value="ERW"/><font size="4">ERW</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S19" value="ERWModule"/><font size="4">ERWModule</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S20" value="ERVMod"/><font size="4">ERVMod </font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S21" value="EvapBP"/><font size="4">EvapBP</font>
            <br><br>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="S22" value="PreEvap"/><font size="4">PreEvap</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S23" value="XP"/><font size="4">XP</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S24" value="Extended"/><font size="4">Extend</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S25" value="FanWall"/><font size="4">FanWall</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S26" value="FillStat"/><font size="4">FillStat</font>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="S27" value="FFilt"/><font size="4">FFilt</font>
                  <br><br>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" name="S28" value="PFilt"/><font size="4">PFilt</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S29" value="CarbFilt"/><font size="4">CarbFilt</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S30" value="CustFilt"/><font size="4">CustFilt </font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S31" value="MGH(H)"/><font size="4">MGH(H)</font>
             <input type="checkbox" name="S32" value="GHeat"/><font size="4">GHeat</font>
             <br><br>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="S33" value="HighStatic"/><font size="4">HighStatic</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S34" value="HGBP"/><font size="4">HGBP</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S35" value="HGRH"/><font size="4">HGRH</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S36" value="HPConv"/><font size="4">HPConv</font>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="S37" value="GFHumid"/><font size="4">GFHumid</font>
                  <br><br>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" name="S38" value="TOHumid"/><font size="4">TOHumid</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S39" value="MHGRH"/><font size="4">MHGRH</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S40" value="LowAF"/><font size="4">LowAF</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S41" value="LowAFSF"/><font size="4">LowAFSF</font>
             <input type="checkbox" name="S42" value="LowAmbient"/><font size="4">LowAmbient</font>
             <br><br>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="S43" value="MEHeat(R)"/><font size="4">MEHeat(R)</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S44" value="MEHeat(I)"/><font size="4">MEHeat(I)</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S45" value="MGH(R)"/><font size="4">MGH(R)</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S46" value="MGH(H)"/><font size="4">MGH(H)</font>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="S47" value="MtrRR"/><font size="4">MtrRR</font>
                  <br><br>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" name="S48" value="MotorGM"/><font size="4">MotorGM</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S49" value="MZ-Mod"/><font size="4">MZ-Mod</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S50" value="NatConv"/><font size="4">NatConv</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S51" value="OAFMS"/><font size="4">OAFMS</font>
             <input type="checkbox" name="S52" value="OSMotor"/><font size="4">OSMotor</font>
             <br><br>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="S53" value="MZ-VAV"/><font size="4">MZ-VAV</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S54" value="Mon"/><font size="4">Mon</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S55" value="PumpPkg"/><font size="4">PumpPkg</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S56" value="PipePkg"/><font size="4">PipePkg</font>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="S57" value="ServLite"/><font size="4">ServLite</font>
                  <br><br>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" name="S58" value="SparkRes"/><font size="4">SparkRes</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S59" value="SSLube"/><font size="4">SSLube</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S60" value="UVLights"/><font size="4">UVLights</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S61" value="VSComp"/><font size="4">VSComp</font>
            <br><br>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="S62" value="LCVAV"/><font size="4">LCVAV</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S63" value="XFVAV"/><font size="4">XFVAV</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S64" value="WCCond"/><font size="4">WCCond</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S65" value="WSHPConv"/><font size="4">WSHPConv</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S66" value="3RConv"/><font size="4">3RConv</font>
                 <br><br>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="S67" value="WiringGM"/><font size="4">WiringGM</font>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="S68" value="XFan"/><font size="4">XFan</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S69" value="RFan"/><font size="4">RFan</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S70" value="SFan"/><font size="4">SFan</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S71" value="OAHood"/><font size="4">OAHood</font>
            <br><br>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="S72" value="XAHood"/><font size="4">XAHood</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S73" value="XALouver"/><font size="4">XALouver</font>
               <input type="checkbox" name="S74" value="OALouver"/><font size="4">OALouver</font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="S75" value="SteamCoil"/><font size="4">SteamCoil</font>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="S76" value="HWCoil"/><font size="4">HWCoil</font>
                 <br><br>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="S77" value="CHWCoil"/><font size="4">CHWCoil</font>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="S78" value="CondCoil"/><font size="4">CondCoil</font>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="S79" value="DXCoil"/><font size="4">DXCoil</font>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="S80" value="F&BP"/><font size="4">F&BP</font>
            <input type="checkbox" name="S81" value="Xfrmr"/><font size="4">Xfrmr</font>
            <br><br>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="S82" value="WCCond"/><font size="4">WCCond</font>
              <input type="checkbox" name="S83" value="PLFrHX"/><font size="4">PlFrHX</li></font>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>



<script>

function updateParent() {    
s = "";
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
      chk = eval("self.document.childForm.t" + i);
      if (chk.checked)
            s += chk.value + ", ";
}
opener.document.parentForm.toppings.value = s;
self.close();

}

</script>
```

Comment: Please create fiddle or format your code.

Comment: In the function "SendValueToParent" you've got `document.getElementById('Scope[]').value;` but there's no element with ID "Scope[]" anywhere on the page. You have lots of checkboxes whose name is "Scope[]", but no element with that ID. You need to find all the ticked checkboxes, get their values (which you also haven't defined currently), and then concatenate those values into a string which you can assign to myVal.

Comment: Thank you ADyson with your direction I have made many of changes. Now the issue is when i click submit on the pop up all of the checkboxs are cleared and there values are passed to the address bar of the popup window.